# VS code runs python with no errors only if started from conda terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

One of the projects that I work on in Python is pretty big and uses a lot of libraries.
I started developing it in Spyder then switched to VS Code.
I also use conda environment.

The problem is with VS Code only: when I open VS Code itself and try to run the project - I get all kinds of import errors.

However, if I open the conda terminal first and just type "code" in it and execute it - the VS Code opens, I can select my project and everything runs just fine, no errors.

In both cases the environment is the same, I did the Ctrl+Shift+P to select it, plus it shows as selected in the bottom left corner anyway. It's the default env.

How can I fix this so I don't have to start VS Code from conda terminal each time?

Comment: Did you follow https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments to use Conda environments in VSCode?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use the base environment for development. Create a new, separate environment for each project/application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the problem was so I'll just leave it here in case it may happen to someone else.

My VS Code was using Powershell as the default shell, even though the input was right with the correct conda env selected (the base in my case), even with running

```
conda activate base
```

command to ensure it, it would still somehow mess up and complain about missing imports

So the solution was to set the default shell in VSC to regular Windows cmd.exe - that was the only needed change

Answer (score 0):

at the conda the modules are installed by default.

in vscode or any other of ides you have to install it manually.

open your terminal or cmd and type:
pip install *module-name*

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this doesn't make much sense.